# Is it possible to Query the SSO information?

Tags: single-sign-on

I wanted to know whether it is possible to query the SSO information present in this [link](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/sso_saml_idp_values.htm) like Issuer, Idnetity Provider Login URL etc through APEX.

Answer (score 2):

The SObject that represents the SSO information is known as the `SamlSsoConfig` object. It is not directly available in Apex Code, but it can be queried and modified through a [Visualforce Metadata API call](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18843/using-meta-data-api-in-apex), which requires Visualforce to handle the asynchronous nature of the [Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/).