# How can we count number of custom labels in salesforce?

Tags: soql, customlabel

How can we count number of custom labels available in Apex class in Salesforce? 
Do we have any query for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Metadata API with the following solution.

1. Login to [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com).
2. Go to 'Migration | Retrieve'
3. Upload package.xml below
4. Unzip output and count number of labels by `<fullname>`

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabel</name>
    </types>
    <version>37.0</version>
</Package>
```

To do that in Apex, you may get more details in the shared [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18843/using-meta-data-api-in-apex).
By deploying to your org, there's a demo page that does so.

[image]
[image]

-end-

Comment: Instead of manual counting, you can use this [tool](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) to count the `<fullname>` nodes.

Comment: Thanks @EugeneO ..but I want to use this count in Apex class. How can I do this?

Comment: @oookkk, updated answer with my own testing above, you may refer shared the referenced solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Metadata API. Take a look at [Andrew Fawcett's Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API.](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)

With the API you can query the [CustomLabels](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customlabels.htm) metadata type to get the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is probably Workbench>Info>Metadata Types & Components>CustomLabel and check the number

[image: Workbench]

Comment: but I want to use this count in Apex class. How can I do this?

Comment: You should start by putting that info in your question.

Comment: thanks..Is there is any query ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible for now. You can vote this Idea.

[Custom Labels count](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000j3cTAAQ)