# Setting up a Named Credential for the Salesforce Rest Api

Tags: lightning-aura-components, rest-api

Does anyone know of a guide for setting up a named credential for a Salesforce Org to access it's own API? This is a required step when using Apex from a Lightning Component. I know that the API does not support Basic authentication so does this mean that you have to go through all the steps of setting up a connected app and auth provider? I am sure someone has set this up but I just can't find any official or unofficial guide on the complete flow of accessing the Rest API from a Lightning Component.

**Edit to add scenario**

I just want to add a simple scenario to better explain the problem. This scenario works from Visualforce today.

Let's say I have a Lightning Component that I want to display search results in. The Salesforce Admin has already configured which fields show in search results using standard functionality. I want to grab that configuration from the [search layouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_retrieve_search_layouts.htm) REST resource (I understand this needs to be from my Apex controller). **What steps do I need to take to allow the Lightning Component's Apex controller to obtain access to this REST API?** If I include this component in a managed package, how much of the setup can I package and how much must be performed by an admin after installation?

Comment: what exactly is it you are trying to do via the API (or in general) ?

Comment: Get page layout information.

Comment: if i am not mistaken, you can only achieve this using the metadata api, [Using Meta data api in apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18843/using-meta-data-api-in-apex)

Comment: Salesforce introduced the User Interface API recently which actually gives the info in a much more usable format (bundled with record info). The rest API also has a standard `layouts` resource which gives layout info for the running user. I am using this in VF right now but because of the issues with authentication I can't get it running from a Lightning Component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Known Issues - [Generating a Session Id from Lightning Domain Provides Invalid Session Id](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EAUPQA4&title=summer-17-generating-a-session-id-from-lightning-domain-provides-invalid-session-id) suggests it *should* be possible to get a valid session id via `UserInfo.getSessionId()`. I'm a bit surprised by this as it seems to contradict [most](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/68235/102) [other](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/55380/102) [posts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/111396/102) that say they don't want you doing this.

However, the particularly interesting part here on the Known Issues is that it is

> SCHEDULED - WINTER '18

So if you can wait till the next release, you might find you can just directly grab a valid Session ID in the Apex controller. You could try this now in a pre-release org, but I'm not sure how to tell if the fix has been applied there or not.

---

**Update 24th August 2017:**

Tested on GS0.

Current status making API calls from `UserInfo.getSessionId()` returned via an @AuraEnabled controller method to a Lightning Component...

> INVALID_SESSION_ID: This session is not valid for use with the API.

I think this corresponds to an AuthSession with the SessionType **Aura**.

Comment: Wow, great find. I am now even more confused now since as you mention Salesforce has made it sound like the current behavior is by design and cannot change for security reasons. I will see if it is possible to get in touch with someone from their side to verify that they are actually making a fix for this.