# How do I create/modify Custom Labels programatically?

Tags: apex

Is there any possibility to create/modify programmatically custom labels using APEX or any other programming language?

As far as I observe there is a possibility to access them via

```
Label.your_label_name
```

But not able to create any or update it.

Comment: You can use metadata api for that.

Answer (score 6):

[Custom Labels](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customlabels.htm) are part of Metadata API. You can create it and modify by means of tools, that work with metadata. For example, using [ant migration tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_deploying_ant.htm).

In apex you can do it with Andrew Fawcett's  [Apex Metadata API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18843/using-meta-data-api-in-apex)